# Replacing text instead of appending in d3 & Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, sapui5

I am using a combination of Javascript+jQuery & d3.js to create custom Chart elements in SAP UI5 dashboard.

In my `render` function in gauge.ds, I have below code:

```
this.render = function()
    {
        this.body = d3.select("#" + this.placeholderName)
                            .append("svg:svg")
                            .attr("class", "gauge")
                            .attr("width", this.config.size + 10)
                            .attr("height", this.config.size + 10);

        this.body.append("svg:circle")
                    .attr("cx", this.config.cx)
                    .attr("cy", this.config.cy)
                    .attr("r", this.config.raduis)
                    .style("fill", "#ccc")
                    .style("stroke", "#000")
                    .style("stroke-width", "0.5px");

        this.body.append("svg:circle")
                    .attr("cx", this.config.cx)
                    .attr("cy", this.config.cy)
                    .attr("r", 0.9 * this.config.raduis)
                    .style("fill", "#fff")
                    .style("stroke", "#e0e0e0")
                    .style("stroke-width", "2px");

        if (undefined != this.config.label)
        {
            var fontSize = Math.round(this.config.size / 12);
            this.body.append("svg:text")
                        .attr("x", this.config.cx)
                        .attr("y", this.config.cy * 2 + fontSize / 2)
                        .attr("dy", fontSize / 2)
                        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                        .text(this.config.label)
                        .style("font-size", fontSize + "px")
                        .style("fill", "#333")
                        .style("stroke-width", "0px");
        }
```

This creates a gauge and there is a label beside that gauge as shown in the image.

[image]

Now in my `redraw` function, I want to replace this label with a new text. I have written following code but it does not work as it writes over previous label and both are visible now on one another.

```
this.redraw = function(value)
{
var fontSize = Math.round(this.config.size / 12);
                this.body.append("svg:text")
                            .attr("x", this.config.cx)
                            .attr("y", this.config.cy * 2 + fontSize / 2)
                            .attr("dy", fontSize / 2)
                            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                            .text(value)
                            .style("font-size", fontSize + "px")
                            .style("fill", "#333")
                            .style("stroke-width", "0px");
}
```

What code should I change to replace the text in the label instead of writing over it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give an ID to your text in the `render` function:

```
this.body.append("svg:text")
    .attr("id", "textLabel")
    //etc...
```

And select by class in the `redraw` function:

```
this.body.select("#textLabel")
    .text(value)
```

If that is the only `<text>` element in the SVG selection, you could simply do...

```
this.body.select("text")
    .text(value)
```

... without any ID or class.

A third solution is naming a selection **outside** both function, which you could change inside them.

Finally, two advices:

First, you said *"I am using a combination of jQuery & d3.js"*. That's almost always a terrible idea. Don't do that.

Second, I'd advise you to mind the names of your variables and objects. You are referring to a SVG selection as `body`. Normally, we would expect that `this.body` refers to the `<body>`. Thus, change it to `this.svg`, it's clearer for whoever is reading your code.

Comment: Worked like a charm ! Thanks a lot for suggestions and feedback. I will try to incorporate them in my code. Really appreciate it.